# Dynamically auto-growing ListView in two layouts

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have an application that I could enter a digit in a EditText element and when I push the "add" button, this digit will be copied to the ListView

I can do it when the ListView in the same activity with the button and the ListView

but when I change the ListView to another activity the app crashes and this is the logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{shop.ned.shahbaa/shop.ned.shahbaa.Item1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at shop.ned.shahbaa.Item1.onCreate(Item1.java:38)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**How can I solve this please?**

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#992222"
        android:text="@string/label_add_new_product_quantity"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextQuantityAddProduct"
        android:hint="@string/add_number"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:inputType="number|phone"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:id="@+id/unit_KG"
        android:textColor="#992222"
        android:text="@string/unit_KG"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0" />


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.5sp"
        android:background="#ffCDCC"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#992222"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/label"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0" />


    <TextView
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:id="@+id/label_Item2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#992222"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/label_Item2"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.5sp"
        android:background="#ffCDCC"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonConfirmAddProduct"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="#D00000"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:text="@string/button_confirm_adding"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_row="7"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_row="8"
        android:layout_column="0" />

</GridLayout>
```

The Class:

```
package shop.ned.shahbaa;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Item1 extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private Button add;
    private ListView cart;
    private ArrayList<String> item;
    private EditText et;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item1);

        add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonConfirmAddProduct);
        cart = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextQuantityAddProduct);
        item = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
            item.add("Row:" + i);
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
        cart.setAdapter(adapter);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                item.add(et.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

like this it's working but I have another listview in another activity with id (shoppingList) and when I change the "cart" id to it, the app crashes.

Comment: what do you mean the list is in another activity? is the XML you have posted saved in the file `R.layout.activity_item1`?

Comment: Yes I said here it is working fine with the XML and Class I have posted, but when I change the id to another ListView which is in another layout it doesn't work.

Comment: that's how android works, and that's why i have asked you about the XML, i assumed the posted code is the one that generates the error, anyways, you CAN NOT `findViewById()` for a view that is located in another XML file other than the one you used in `setContentView()` unless it's included inside it.

Comment: thank you very much about these information, so is there any way to match the list view from the other layout to this activity?

Comment: well, i am not sure about your business logic, and what you are trying to achieve but i see the safest method is to start the 2nd activity and pass the needed data (using extras in intent's bundle) then the 2nd activity should load it's layout, and populate the listView.